# recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) when connect with edge connection

Tags: android, json

I make a android application,I get some data from server with json.
When I use of wifi my application work very well but when i use edge connction(mobile internet connection) my app onstop

My code:

```
    try {      

                JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();  
                toSend.put("city_id", 6); 
                toSend.put("offset",con);      
                toSend.put("_count",10);
                JSONObject json = toSend;
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000000);

                JSONObject jsonResponse = null;   
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://"+getResources().getString(R.string.address)+"/include/json/sale.php");
                try {
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
                    post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    post.setEntity(se);  

                    HttpResponse response;
                    response = client.execute(post);
                    String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);

                } catch (Exception e) { 

                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage()); 

                }

             if(jsonResponse.get("products").toString().equals("{\"product\":\"empty\"}")){Log.d("Companies","NULL"); }

            JSONArray array=jsonResponse.getJSONArray("products");      

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {   
                JSONObject json_data = array.getJSONObject(i);           
                JSONArray arr1=json_data.getJSONArray("product");
                Pro_ID.add(arr1.getString(0));  
                Pro_Name.add(arr1.getString(1));
                Log.d("get from host:", arr1.getString(1));
                Log.d("get from ho****st:", arr1.getString(2));
                Log.d("get from ho****st:", arr1.getString(6));
                Pro_Logo.add("http://sellprojects.ir/"+arr1.getString(5));
                Pro_Price.add(arr1.getString(3));
                Pro_Descount.add(arr1.getString(4));
                Pro_Company.add(arr1.getString(6));

    }  
    con+=10;  

        } catch (JSONException e) {           

            Log.e("JSONException:::", e.getMessage());         


        }
```

Log Cat:

> 11-17 12:43:48.792: E/ERROR(21237): recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at Fragments.SalesFragment$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(SalesFragment.java:186)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at Fragments.SalesFragment$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(SalesFragment.java:1)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>   11-17 12:43:48.807: E/AndroidRuntime(21237):    ... 4 more
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237): Activity com.example.rastak.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42a2e1b0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-513,144} that was originally added here
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.rastak.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42a2e1b0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-513,144} that was originally added here
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at Fragments.SalesFragment$MyAsyncTask.onPreExecute(SalesFragment.java:245)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at Fragments.SalesFragment.onCreateView(SalesFragment.java:79)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>   11-17 12:43:49.152: E/WindowManager(21237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)